# How to convert CSV string into a multi column result in PL/SQL?

Tags: csv, plsql

Let's assume I have a string like this:

```
a;b;c#d,e,f#g,h,i#j,k,l#m,n,o
```

The `;` is used to separate the columns, the `#` for separating rows, so the result should be something like this with the example above:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| a       | b       | c       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| d       | e       | f       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| g       | h       | i       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| j       | k       | l       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

And the question is - as I wrote it in the title - if it's possible to write an SQL `SELECT` which gives the expected result?

Comment: When Googling for this I saw many resources available, have you tried any of them?  Note that in general you should avoid storing CSV or other unnormalized data in your tables.

Comment: I was blind unfortunately :(. Although I **did see** the answer for my question, at first somewhy I didn't realize that **it is the solution** for my answer, but "thanks" for your comment, checking it for the 2nd time I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, sorry for the noob question. Here is the solution code, maybe in the future it will be helpful for others:

```
WITH
  splitted_rows as (
    SELECT TRIM(regexp_substr('a;b;c#d,e,f#g,h,i#j,k,l#m,n,o', '[^#]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS str
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count('a;b;c#d,e,f#g,h,i#j,k,l#m,n,o', '#') + 1)
SELECT regexp_substr(sr.str, '[^#]+', 1, 1) as column1
      ,regexp_substr(sr.str, '[^#]+', 1, 2) as column2
      ,regexp_substr(sr.str, '[^#]+', 1, 3) as column3
  FROM splitted_rows sr
```